# I'm having some trouble with css

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex, namespaces, adobe

I keep getting this warning in css:

```
Type 'AutoComplete' in CSS selector 'AutoComplete' must be qualified with a namespace.
```

I can't seem to get it fixed. Any ideas? I've tried adding namespaces but no go. :S

Comment: @Dennis You're getting that warning in the browser?

Comment: No sorry, it's in the application debug.

Comment: @Dennis What application? On which line does the error occur?

Comment: It says line two, which I'm going to guess it is referring to my css file? But that is just my guess. I've only ever had the problem with name spaces in css.

Comment: You need to post more information. I'm voting to close as the question isn't answerable in the current form.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Notice the Flash tags on this question, I think it's an ActionScript error?

Comment: @Dennis It says line two, but it doesn't say which file?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark, some of the components have the same names as some of the older mx components. For this reason, adobe requires namespaces when declaring CSS Styles, like the following:

```
<Style>
  @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"; (mx components)
  @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"; (spark components)
</Style>
```

This goes in the top of your CSS stylesheet. If you look at  your <Application> code in the root of your project, you will see something like the following:

```
<s:Application ... xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" ...>
```

In this case, your stylesheet.css would need the following:

```
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Components in the CSS file must have their namespace specified.  At the top of the CSS file should be something like:

@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

And your CSS declaration for the AutoComplete from should look something like this:

mx|Form{
//Some style stuff
}

Substitute mx and Form with AutoComplete and its namespace respectively.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [site](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/comment-page-3/), adding something this to your CSS should help:

```
    @namespace components “com.hillelcoren.components.*”;

    components|AutoComplete
    {
    selected-item-style-name: macMail;
    }
```